# Icon Overlap CSS in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

[image]

Encountered using Chrome `36.0.1985.125` on Mac OS X (10.9.4). It is not present in Firefox on either Mac or Linux. I'm not a Moderator (or 10K user) on any other sites, so I can't test and see if this is a issue across the board or not.

Comment: Lately you've been hitting all the bugs S:

Comment: It's your fault you have so many badges and rep!

Comment: @Braiam lol. :P

Comment: @oded: Additional hint: I browse the web zoomed out in chrome to 90%, because I've got a small screen. Going to 100% 'solves' the problem. If that makes this a "user error", i'm ok with that.

Comment: Ah... yeah, we specifically don't support zooming...

Comment: Yay! User error! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support zooming at this point in time...

So, yes, visual "glitches" are expected in such cases.

Comment: BOOO!!!!!!!!1ONE